# win 8.1 don't send status report to wsus 3 sp2 will all patches

Tags: wsus, windows-8.1

There are a lots of pages in internet which deals about wsus problems with windows 8.1 but mine is not covered.
I have a wsus 3.0 sp2 installed on a 2008 server and it has all the necessary patches for windows 8 (KB2720211 and KB2734608)
In the domain there are win xp, win 7 and 3 win 8.1 computers. 
Cannot say if win 8 computers can download and apply updates from wsus, may be it will be the subject of a new post here.
Inside wsus selecting a computer group I can see a column with a header which translated from my language sound like "Last Status report".
All 3 Win 8.1 computers are switched on daily and there are not major and evident configuration differences between them.
Unfortunately only one them seems to send the "Status report" daily.

On one of the 'lazy' computer I performed the following steps:

- Net stop wuauserv
- rd /s %windir%\softwaredistribution\
- Net start wuauserv
- wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow

The first command says that wuauserv was not running.
Anyway the "Last status report" in wsus is finally updated with the date and time of the manual intervention.
After that it doesn't change any more till the next time I perform a new manual intervention.

I checked and compared the most relevant registry keys between the 'lazy' and the smart computer but found nothing useful.
Don't know what to do.

Here is a possibly related event:

```
Windows Error Reporting
Event Id 1001
Data:       24/01/2014
Ora:        11.51.13
WindowsUpdateFailure2; Non disponibile; 0; 7.9.9600.16403; 80246003; 6D629889-8D3F-4F26-929A-E08B8F363F49; Download; 101; Managed {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}; 0; ; ; ; ; ; ; 0; 7086d3c9-84e5-11e3-be7b-7446a08f08b8; 262144;
```

and here the content of ReportingEvents.log

```
{3BAE0BA3-0470-4239-8F5D-D49549F5FC5A}  2014-01-24 11:51:08:012+0100    1   147 [AGENT_DETECTION_FINISHED]  101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   Windows Update Command Line Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 2 updates.
{4976B83B-B852-4323-B0EE-BEAAA51BE717}  2014-01-24 11:51:08:012+0100    1   156 [AGENT_STATUS_30]   101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   Windows Update Command Line Success Pre-Deployment Check    Reporting client status.
{6DD15230-6226-44B3-AD66-22E1A141AB27}  2014-01-24 11:51:09:259+0100    1   161 [AGENT_DOWNLOAD_FAILED] 101 {79AE03DF-D6EB-4DE2-B59F-37E963D7A69E}  101 80096004    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Download    Error: Download failed.
{682DBBA8-10D6-4B40-AD37-F30539186AE6}  2014-01-24 11:51:10:134+0100    1   161 [AGENT_DOWNLOAD_FAILED] 101 {6D629889-8D3F-4F26-929A-E08B8F363F49}  100 80246003    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Download    Error: Download failed.
```

Comment: Are these machines joined to AD? How does the Group Policy for this machines look like?

Comment: All computers are inside AD, WSUS settings are applied through the same Group Policy which works well with all Xp, Win7 and one win 8.1 machines.

Comment: You could try a `wsusutil checkhealth` on the WSUS server to check if there is a problem with the server itself before you start investigating on the client.

Comment: It complains about an high error rate in computer updates. Only one message, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Time to time I went on investigating the problem and surfing the net to check if somebody else was struggling the same battle.
I went on the Wsus server and in the IIS log I found:

```
2014-08-05 06:03:52 192.168.1.11 POST /ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx - 80 - 192.168.1.160 Windows-Update-Agent/7.9.9600.17195+Client-Protocol/1.21 200 0 0 56
```

It is about the the Win8.1 whose last status report is not updated inside wsus.
This is the proof that the client correctly sends a report to Wsus.
Following step was to watch Wsus own log file, **SoftwareDistribution.log** in C:\Program Files\Update Services\LogFiles.

```
2014-08-05 06:03:52.879 UTC Warning w3wp.5  UpdateStatusEventHandler.HandleEvent    Error parsing misc data for ComputerID=f8176ceb-7b70-408d-8887-bfb4453fb5ee, EventInstanceID=13a76563-a409-4949-91ad-92b8b9c6a529, Cause:Error occurred while parsing MiscData for event. MiscData element g=6D629889-8D3F-4F26-929A-E08B8F363F49|79AE03DF-D6EB-4DE2-B59F-37E963D7A69E.
```

From what I can understand the report was discarded because not well formed.

On client computer I checked the **WindowsUpdate.log** file where there are these interestimng lines:

```
2014-08-05  07:55:30:472     564    f2b8    Report  REPORT EVENT: {5387A352-656F-4DD8-A3AF-979972950952}    2014-08-05 07:55:25:462+0200    1   161 [AGENT_DOWNLOAD_FAILED] 101 {79AE03DF-D6EB-4DE2-B59F-37E963D7A69E}  101 80096004    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Download    Error: Download failed.

2014-08-05  07:55:30:472     564    f2b8    Report  REPORT EVENT: {85064B2B-1FAB-477D-AF0E-4CC8C8DC520F}    2014-08-05 07:55:25:525+0200    1   161 [AGENT_DOWNLOAD_FAILED] 101 {6D629889-8D3F-4F26-929A-E08B8F363F49}  100 80246003    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Download    Error: Download failed.
```

Checking windows update on the client there were two downloaded updates which failed to install.
I judged they were not so important, so I went inside wsus and rejected them for Win 8 computer group.

It seems the problem is solved and after few days I could see a valid last reporting status for the Win 8.1 computers.